# SQL query group rows by column PRN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i need a bit of help with the SQL query below

```
DECLARE @company nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @theweek date

SET @company = 'RWF'
SET @theweek = '2014-02-03'

SELECT [thedate],[PRN],[StartTime] ,[FinishTime],[Grade],[BreakTime],[TotalCost],[Department],[CompanyCode]
FROM LabourHireCost 
WHERE thedate BETWEEN @THEWEEK AND CONVERT(datetime, @theweek) +7 
ORDER BY CompanyCode, PRN, thedate
```

this return result like this( below ) but what i would like to do if possible is return the employee and the times worked for the week

```
    Thedate    PRN  Start   Finish  Grade Break  Cost   Department Company
| 2014-02-03 | 179 | 06:00 | 06:00 | 2  | 01:00 | 26.17 |      2   |   DH  |   
| 2014-02-04 | 179 | 06:00 | 06:00 | 3  | 01:00 | 36.17 |      2   |   DH  | 
| 2014-02-03 | 178 | 06:00 | 06:00 | 2  | 01:00 | 26.17 |      2   |   DH  | 
| 2014-02-04 | 178 | 06:00 | 06:00 | 4  | 01:00 | 46.17 |      2   |   DH  |
```

i was thinking of something like this

```
PRN 179
 Thedate      Start   Finish  Grade Break  Cost   Department Company 
| 2014-02-03 | 06:00 | 06:00 | 2  | 01:00 | 26.17 |  2   |   DH  |
| 2014-02-04 | 06:00 | 06:00 | 3  | 01:00 | 36.17 |  2   |   DH  |

PRN 178
| 2014-02-03 | 06:00 | 06:00 | 2  | 01:00 | 26.17 |  2   |   DH  | 
| 2014-02-04 | 06:00 | 06:00 | 4  | 01:00 | 46.17 |  2   |   DH  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current results vs. expected results, it looks like the query is already returning the data that you want.  If you want to present it differently, that would be done in your client application (whether it is web app, reporting software, or even Excel), but SQL Server generally should not be used for breaking datasets into nicely formatted reports.

Comment: i was able to do this in the Front End PHP application

Answer (score 0):

Well how about using a cte to calculate the amount of time everyone (time frame between start and finish )worked on x date and then selecting it?

Answer (score 0):

This looks speciously like a homework assignment.  I believe what you are looking for though is a join http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29